# Regular expressions with scanf in C

Tags: c, regex, string, scanf

I'm trying to achieve the following without any success:

Removing the opening

> message "

and trailing

> "

while leaving the content in between, and saving it into my variable, using sscanf regular expressions.
I wrote the following code:

```
sscanf( buffer, "message \"%[^\"]", message)
```

Which works good when I have something like message "Hey there", **but** when I'm trying the following string, I get only the white space between the two quotation marks.

> message " """ This is a Test """ "

The result for this should be """ This is a Test """

Is there a way to upgrade my expression so it will include this extreme event of message? I tried to look it up both in google and here, and couldn't find an elegant answer. I'm aware that it's possible using string manipulation with a lot lines of code, but I'm trying something more simple here.

**P.S. The trailing " is the end of the expression, and is a must by the program, after that comes nothing.**

Thanks in advance for the feedback!

Comment: will there be anything after the trailing `"`?

Comment: if not you can use `. ` instead of `[^\"]`

Comment: No, the trailing " is the end of the whole expression.

Comment: @Fallenhero sscanf( buffer, "message \"%.  ", message) ? That doesn't seem right

Comment: How do you (want to) decide if a `"` is the terminating `"` or part of the string?

Comment: @WernerHenze I guess I need to add an if check for the last char in the string, and delete it once its a " right?

Comment: @BoazKG You need to know the specification. And yes, reading everything after **message "** and afterwards checking if the last character was a `"` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine with not using regex for the whole thing:

Original version:

```
sscanf(buffer, "message \"%[^$]", message); // remove 'message "'
message[strlen(message) - 1] = '\0'; // remove trailing '"'
```

Safe, correct, and generic version:

```
char* buffer = ...;
const char* prefix = "message \"";
const char* suffix = "\"";

if (strstr(buffer, prefix) != buffer) {
    // error, doesn't start with `prefix`
}

buffer += strlen(prefix);

char* suffixStart = strrchr(buffer, suffix[0]);
if (!suffixStart || strcmp(suffixStart, suffix) != 0) {
    // error, doesn't end with `suffix`
}

*suffixStart = '\0'; // strip `suffix`
```

Comment: This code has a buffer overflow if message is not big enough and undefined behavior if strlen(message)==0 and probably if message had not been read at all.

Comment: The characters in a scan set are not really a regex.  The format shown won't parse `message "send $20 immediately"` correctly; it will stop at the $ symbol.

Comment: @WernerHenze Fixed.

Comment: Much better.  Note that the blank in the `scanf()` format matches zero or more white space characters, formally.  Your `strstr()` formulation doesn't quite do that, but it is probably forgivable.  The `scanf()` family are endlessly subtle and frequently exasperating.

Comment: This usage of `strstr()` look like `strncmp()`.